# Capitalization of language names in a list

Tags: typography

I don't know if my question belongs here but anyway.

Should we capitalize language names in a list? Because I saw things like that

[image]

(OpenStreetMap Wiki)

[image]

(Wikipedia)

Which seems weird to me. First, it looks bad, and then, why are English and Esperanto capitalized while Spanish and Italian are not?

Comment: Try not to expand your knowledge, intuition and wabts into other languages. You will fail.

Comment: @joojaa habits or wabbits?  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English, the names of languages and countries are always capitalized. They're considered to be "proper nouns".

All proper nouns are capitalized in English. It's a rule or convention in English orthography. It's just what we do. Don't try to rationalize it.  This rule also applies to names, towns, cities, regions, titles, organisations, days of the week, and months of the year, holidays such as Easter, and Christmas, but not seasons such as winter/summer which are instead considered "common nouns". Common nouns are not capitalised in English.

Other languages have their own rules for capitalization. In German for example, all nouns are capitalized.

Language names such as "español" or "italiano" are not English words. In English these languages are called Spanish and Italian. Therefore since Spanish and Italian don't capitalise these words, I would argue that they should never be capitalized where they appear when actually written in those languages, unless of course they're the first word in a sentence.

If instead those language names were translated into the English names for them, then they should all be capitalized. Conversely, if all these languages names were translated into Spanish, they should all have initial lower case letters.  Even "inglés", and "alemán".

As far as I know (and I'm no expert) the same lower case rule for language names applies in Spanish, French, and Italian. I'm not really sure about any other languages or what their particular rules are. A linguist/polyglot would be better placed to answer that.

Comment: I still think it's strange, in this case, to put non-capitalized words because in spanish for example, even if the word is a common noun, at the beggining of a sentence it would be capitalized. Here all the languages names appears to me like small sentences as this is not a sentence but a list

Comment: @TheDevKiller said languages like suomi actually have rules for lists too and specify noncapitalisation of list items

Comment: @joojaa oooh I didn't know that! Then it's alright